# Is it possible to use shades with draw macros?

Tags: metafun

Is it possible to achieve shades (`linear`, `circular`, etc.)

[image]

with the `draw` macros (`draw`, `drawarrow`, etc.)?

I tried with the following code but it fails by returning a blank page.

```
\startMPpage
  path p ; p = origin -- (100,100) ;
  draw p withshademethod "linear"
         withshadevector (0,1)
         withshadecolors (red,blue) ;
\stopMPpage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shading only works with filling, but one can come up with hacks for imitating shading of drawing. One would be to run along the path and fill small disks with a varying color. Another is to use an envelope.

```
\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  path p ; p = origin -- (100,100) -- cycle ;
  fill (envelope pensquare of p)
        withshademethod "linear"
        withshadevector (0,100)
        withshadecolors (red,blue) ;
\stopMPpage

\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  path p ; p = origin -- (100,100) -- cycle ;
  fill (envelope pensquare rotated 45 of p)
        withshademethod "linear"
        withshadevector (0,100)
        withshadecolors (red,blue) ;
\stopMPpage

\startMPpage[offset=1dk]
  path p ; p := (10,20) .. (50,100) .. (20,40) ;;
  fill (envelope pensquare rotated 45 of p)
        withshademethod "linear"
        withshadevector (0,100)
        withshadecolors (red,blue) ;
\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

Result:

[image: ex1]

[image: ex2]

[image: ex3]

As you see in the third example, the output is not the expected one. It seems only to work with straight paths.